# Remove quotes from QueryString in a htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

In a htaccess file, I want to redirect URLs from an old site with a query string including quote `'` or apostrophe `’` to new URLs by removing quote or apostrophe and after an anchor.

### Example:

Old URL: `http://my_site.com/?qa_faqs=la-csg-crds-quelles-sont-les-sommes-concernees-par-l’abattement-pour-frais-professionnels-applique-sur-l’assiette-de-la-csg-crds`

New URL: `http://my_site.com/qa_faqs/#la-csg-crds-quelles-sont-les-sommes-concernees-par-labattement-pour-frais-professionnels-applique-sur-lassiette-de-la-csg-crds`

For the other clean URLs, this script is OK :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^qa_faqs=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /qa_faqs/#%1? [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following rules to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(qa_faqs)=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/%2? [DPI,E=QUOTES:1]

RewriteRule ^(qa_faqs/.+?)['’](.+?)$ $1$2 [NC,DPI,E=QUOTES:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:QUOTES} =1
RewriteRule ^(qa_faqs)/([^'’]+)$ /$1#$2 [R=302,NC,NE,L]
```

These rules will do following:

1. Remove query string
2. Remove quotes
3. Redirecting query parameter in `#` (anchor)

Comment: Hi anubhava. Thx for your quick reply. I ll check your method on monday.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I tried your rules but the old URL is still the same : http://my_site.com/?qa_faqs=la-csg-crds-quelles-sont-les-sommes-concernees-par-l’abattement-pour-frais-professionnels-applique-sur-l’assiette-de-la-csg-crds. The website is a WordPress and I don' know is there is an incidence.

Comment: Hi I am traveling till Sat and don't have my laptop with me. Please wait till Saturday l.